# pandas.read_excel with identical column names in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When i import an excel table with pandas.read_excel there is a problem (or a feature :-) ) with identical column names. For example the excel-file has two columns named "dummy", after the import in a datframe the second column is named "dummy.1".
Is there a way to import without the renaming option ?

Comment: I would argue that having two columns with the same name is a problem on its own, any why not let pandas fix it. But having said that, just import the file and regex rename all columns that have a `"\.\n+"` suffix.

Comment: `read_csv` has a mangle option  whick unfortunatelly is not supported yet and it is mentioned here and not included in `read_excel`: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10523. The question is why you would want that and probably if you could just read the file without headers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I don't see the point why you would want this. However, as I could think of a workaround I might as well post it.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.read_excel('text.xlsx', header=None,nrows=1).values[0] # read first row
df = pd.read_excel('text.xlsx', header=None, skiprows=1) # skip 1 row
df.columns = cols

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   col1  col1
0     1     1
1     2     2
2     3     3
```

Comment: This is great as the source file had duplicate columns names.  I needed to transpose (melt, unpivot) the table into a tall dataframe.  This allowed me to keep the matching columns having matching rows.  Thanks!

Comment: Was about to say the same, this is incredibly useful (in fact necessary) if you want to melt the dataframe and group by the duplicate columns. It's quite annoying that @pandas doesn't recognize this and build in a function...

Comment: Very cool trick to *only* read the first row (headers) and then skip precisely that row when reading the whole file.