# Why is pandas changing my types_dict when loading xlsx with duplicate column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading an .xlsx with a duplicate column into a pandas dataframe and experienced unexpected behaviour.

Can anyone tell me what exactly is happening here and why *types_dict* has changed?

*test.xlsx* :

| a | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | b1 | c1 |
| 2 | 2 | b2 | c2 |
| 3 | 3 | b3 | c3 |

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib


type_dict = {'a': str,
             'b': str,
             'c': str,
             }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_excel(pathlib.PurePath('./test.xlsx'), dtype=type_dict)
    print(list(type_dict.keys()))
```

```
>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a.1']
```

Thank you for your input!

Comment: From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html): `mangle_dupe_cols` "Duplicate columns will be specified as ‘X’, ‘X.1’, …’X.N’, rather than ‘X’…’X’. Passing in False will cause data to be overwritten if there are duplicate names in the columns."

Comment: It happens [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f00ed8f47020034e752baf0250483053340971b0/pandas/io/parsers/python_parser.py#L416-L434), your `type_dict` is passed all the way through so when columns are mangled the new column name is added. You should [open a bug report or question](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/new/choose) with `pandas` for more guidance

Answer (score 2):

So this looks to be expected behavior by `read_excel` because it would be following how `read_csv` is doing it.

Like Alex says, there is `mangle_dupe_cols` in the docs that supposedly allow importing of duplicate column names but it's never been implemented. And judging from this [issue 13262 on pandas-dev](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13262), even with community demand, it's hard to add support when there is duplicate column names, and the issue has languished for years.

You can [purview this SO thread for workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653962/pandas-read-excel-with-identical-column-names-in-excel)