# Decimal extension to column header while importing using `pd.read_excel()`

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a '.xlsx' sheet and I am reading specific columns using pandas function `read_excel()`. When I skip rows 2 and 3 using: `df_test = pd.read_excel(file_path, usecols="EA:FU", skiprows=[2,3])`, I get the following result: [First rows are strings][1]. (Note first row has values like 'MAY2', 'JUN2', etc.)

However, as soon as I try to use the first row as the header(or remove the 0th row while reading the excel file) using `df_test = pd.read_excel(file_path, usecols="EA:FU", skiprows=[0,2,3])`, the header values change as: [decimals added at the end of the string][2].(Note column header has an added decimal extension like 'MAY2.2', 'JUN2.2', etc.)

There are multiple times that I do this process on the same excel sheet for different 'usecols' values and everytime there is a decimal addition to it.

I have checked the 'type' of the values in question and they are `str`.

What can I do to get the values without decimal extensions in the column header?
Please suggest steps so that I can understand the issue as well.

I understand that a function can be written to rename each column and remove the decimal extension. However, I am interested in finding the way to properly read the excel sheet as desired.

Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eE10.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDf5y.png

Comment: Are the headers repeated or unique in your sheet? Looks like the headers are not unique.

Comment: Yes the headers are repeated in other columns. How should I deal with that?

Comment: I found this answer from @Anton vBR to be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50655248/18559115